# PCRaster format subcatchment conversion in QGIS 3.16 to polyline

Tags: qgis, line

I'm using QGIS 3.16 and trying to polygonize from raster to vector but then I get the following error " gdal_polygonize.bat failed to start. Either gdal_polygorize.bat is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program. Excecution failed after 0.5 seconds."

How can I export PCRaster subcatchments to polyline?